# react useRef hook when is it wiped?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lifecycle

I am using react functions as components and hooks.
Particularly useRef. here is the hierarchy:
{Page,children:[{onboarding,children:[{user}]}]}
User function uses useRef, like so :

```
const fetchProfileCalled = useRef(false);
 console.log("-- rendering --");

 // some useState, and fetch rest data in useEffect omitted...
 
useEffect(()=>{

 if (!fetchProfileCalled.current) {
   console.log("loading profile");
   fetchProfileCalled.current = true;
   fetchProfile();
 }
},[]);
// ... some render logic omitted here
```

and here is what I see logged when refreshing the page:

```
--rendering--
loading profile
--rendering--
--rendering--
loading profile
--rendering--
--rendering--
--rendering--
```

I expected to see only one "loading profile".
useRef is in place since I wanted to prevent rerender.

More than this code behavior, I could not find anything about the hooks' life cycle. For example when a state hook loses its saved value, same for useRef hook, or any other hooks which are stateful.

Comment: may I ask what the rest of the code looks like, and why would you check it like that? why doent you set a state after the profile was fetched and check based on that. From the code you inserted here , I cannot see why you would use ref?

Comment: you may refer to a basic example I did, maybe it helps you: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-euclid-xm157?file=/src/App.js

Comment: your component is definitely re-created since `useEffect(..., [])` will be run just once per life cycle. Why is it recreated? I cannot tell for sure. My guess there is some conditional rendering in one of its parents, so you are removing element while loading in progress and return it back. But you need to debug anyway.

Comment: @skyboyer thats the answer. I removed all code from the component and noticed it re-renders too many times.